# How to use PostgreSQL/PostGIS with ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, postgresql, arccatalog

Has anyone used PostgreSQL with PostGIS successfully?

I am a semi-experienced ArcGIS user and want to build out a database and connect it to ArcCatalog.

I've scoured the internet for resources but nobody has really given a good walkthrough.