# Configuring ArcMap applications to display WMS from PostGIS/GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wms

I'm afraid I'm quite new to GeoServer and I have been set the task of configuring ArcMap applications to display data from PostGIS/GeoServer.  I  realize that I will need to set up a WMS service in GeoServer but I'm not really sure how one goes about doing this.

If any one can give me some pointers or step by step guide it would be much appreciated.  I have tried Googling it but haven't had much luck.

Comment: Don't forget that if you just need to view the data from PostGIS, in ArcMap 10 you can directly connect to PostGIS layers through a Query Layer.  See these previous questions for more discussion of options: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147/how-can-i-connect-to-a-postgis-database-from-arcmap-9-3-and-10-0 ; http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6749/arcgis-and-postgis

Comment: it's hard to tell if you want to know how to set up GeoServer and PostGIS or how to add a WMS layer in ArcMap.

Answer (score 3):

ArcMap can read/edit postgis (via ArcSDE) and styled normally within ArcMap.

Assuming you **do not** have ArcSDE hence your postgis>geoserver>wms>arcmap route

(assume your postgis and geoserver is setup here)

Geoserver setup
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/index.html
more specifically the output
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/outputformats.html

**before you do this check which images arcmap can read**

[image]

add wms to arcmap

[image]