# Connecting ArcGIS Desktop with PostGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I connect to a PostGIS database from ArcMap 9.3 and 10.0?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147/how-can-i-connect-to-a-postgis-database-from-arcmap-9-3-and-10-0)

I've installed postGIS 1.5.3, and would like to connect it from ArcGIS Destkop v10.

How to do it?

Comment: Very similar to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147/how-can-i-connect-to-a-postgis-database-from-arcmap-9-3-and-10-0

Comment: Also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6749/arcgis-and-postgis

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps start by investigating [Query Layers](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Preparing_to_use_query_layers/00s500000032000000/) (which are read only).
I worked with these on SQL Server Spatial recently for the first time and they seemed to perform well.
If you need read-write, then [ST-Links SpatialKit](http://www.st-links.com/Pages/default.aspx), which I have not tried, appears to have that capability.